# Bounding the degree of very sparse random graph

Tags: probability, asymptotics, random-graphs, network, concentration-of-measure

I am confused with how to manipulating with big O notation ,here is a problem from section 2.4(Exercise 2.4.3) [high dimensional probability](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Ervershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf)  by Roman Vershynin

Consider a random graph $G \sim G(n,p)$ with expected degree $d=O(1)$. Show that with high probability , all vertices of $G$ have degrees $$O (\frac{\log n}{\log \log n})$$

I want use Chernoff bound below to bound the degree of vertices:

$$Pr\left[| X-\mu|\geq \delta \mu \right] \leq 2e^ {-c\mu\delta ^2}$$

where c is a constant  $\DeclareMathOperator*{\E}{\mathbb{E}} \delta \in [0,1), \mu = \E {X}$ and X is binomial random variable.

how should I do that ?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! You can get properly sized parentheses that adjust to their content by preceding them with `\left` and `\right`. You can get proper formatting for operators like $\log$ by using `\log`. For operators that don't have a command of their own, you can use `\operatorname{name}`. Please see [this tutorial and reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) on how to typeset math on this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The degree distribution of a node is $\text{Binomial}(n-1, p)$. Here, the mean is constant, so it is a very skewed binomial distribution (approximately Poisson), and the usual Chernoff bound does not do well in such cases. You can try it, but it will not work.

Instead, we can bound the probability that a node has degree at least $k$ by $\binom{n-1}{k}p^k$: the union bound, over all sets of $k$ nodes, that all nodes in the set are adjacent to the given node. So if $X_{\ge k}$ denotes the number of nodes with degree at least $k$, we have
$$
   \mathbb E[X_{\ge k}] \le n \binom{n-1}{k}p^k \le n \left(\frac{(n-1)e}{k}\right)^k p^k = n \left(\frac{de}{k}\right)^k = \exp\Big(\log n - k \log k + O(k)\Big).
$$
It's pretty common to try to find an asymptotic inverse of something like $f(x) = x \log x$: it is $f^{-1}(x) = (1+o(1)) \frac{x}{\log x}$. Here, to get $\mathbb E[X_{\ge k}] = o(1)$, we want $k \log k$ to outgrow $\log n$, so we should be looking at a value of $k$ like $\frac{\log n}{\log \log n}$.

But if we use $k = \frac{\log n}{\log \log n}$, then we get $k \log k = \log n \cdot (1 - \frac{\log \log \log n}{\log\log n}) < \log n$, which isn't good enough.

Instead, set $k = \frac{2 \log n}{\log \log n}$ (any constant bigger than $1$ would do, actually). Now we get:

- $k \log k = k(\log 2 + \log\log n - \log\log \log n) = (1+o(1)) k \log \log n = (1+o(1)) 2 \log n$.
- Since $k = o(\log n)$, we have $k \log k + O(k) = (1+o(1)) 2\log n$ as well.
- Finally, $\log n - k \log k + O(k)$ becomes $-(1+o(1))\log n$, which goes to $-\infty$ with $n$, so $\exp(\log n - k \log k + O(k)) = o(1)$.

Comment: In the second line, where it say "over all sets of $d$ nodes" it should say $k$ nodes right?

Comment: Yes, and while I was fixing that, I added some details of the final step, too.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is relevant, but the degrees of each vertex are not independent of each other, so how do you get first inequality for $E[X_{\geq k}]?$

Comment: Linearity of expectation does not require independence. It is always true that if each of $n$ things has a $p$ chance of doing something, then the expected number of them that do it is $np$, even if those chances are correlated.

Comment: I see what you're saying, I think a formal way of thinking about it would be to label the vertices $\{1, \ldots, n \}$ and think of $X_{ \geq k}$ as a sum of indicator functions on these vertices.

Comment: Yes, that's the way to formalize it. The idea comes up often enough in the study of random graphs that it's usually not spelled out in that much detail.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the theorem 2.3.1, which is the usual Chernoff's inequality about upper bound can work, we can get almost the same result like the first answer, which is $t \mathrm{log}(t) + O(t) \geq \mathrm{log}(n) - \epsilon$, just show $t = O(\mathrm{log}(n)/\mathrm{log}\mathrm{log}(n)) $